# Object Mapping for Composite Columns with Astyanax

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

For example,

```
@Column("body")
private String body;
```

That will create a column "body"

I'd want to be able to annotate such that I can create a composite column such as "body:foo".

There isn't any example for this purpose or even any indication that this is possible. Does anyone have any more knowledge about this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that this will work with the entity persister, but I would maybe play around with something like:

```java
@Column()
@Serializer(MyCompositeSerializer.class)
private SomeEntity entity;

public class MyCompositeSerializer extends AnnotatedCompositeSerializer<SomeEntity> {
    public MyCompositeSerializer() {
        super(SomeEntity.class);
    }
}
```

Take a look at how `public class AnnotatedCompositeSerializer<T> extends AbstractSerializer<T>` is implemented to get a feel for what you need to do if the above approach doesn't work.